# Must declare the scalar variable “@Login”. Error when trying to add parameter to SqlDataSource

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sqlcommand, sqlparameter

I have this error :
Must declare the scalar variable "@Login".

My code :

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["intranetv2"].ConnectionString))
{

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into [MyBase].[Dbo].[LogErrors] (Username, StackTrace, ShortDescription, DetailDescription, ErrorType) VALUES (@Login, @Stack, @Message, @Txt, @Source)", conn);

                SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
                param.ParameterName = "Login";
                param.Value = user.Login;
                param.ParameterName = "Stack";
                param.Value = ex.StackTrace;
                param.ParameterName = "Message";
                param.Value = ex.Message;
                param.ParameterName = "Txt";
                param.Value = Txt;
                param.ParameterName = "Source";
                param.Value = ex.Source;
                // 3. add new parameter to command object
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
                conn.Open();
                return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

I have try with th e'@' in the param but i have the same error.

Comment: You don't even try to add `Login` as a parameter name - it's overwritten until it's `Source`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must create a new SqlParameter for each Parameter, it should be like this:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["intranetv2"].ConnectionString))
{

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into [MyBase].[Dbo].[LogErrors] (Username, StackTrace, ShortDescription, DetailDescription, ErrorType) VALUES (@Login, @Stack, @Message, @Txt, @Source)", conn);

                SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
                param.ParameterName = "@Login";
                param.Value = user.Login;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

                SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter();
                param2.ParameterName = "@Stack";
                param2.Value = ex.StackTrace;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param2);
    (...)
```

Answer (score 2):

You override `params` value and only ever add one parameter to the query.  Which is `Source`

I'd recommend you create a new variable or use `AddWithValue`.

```
   SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
   param.ParameterName = "Login";
   param.Value = user.Login;

   cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

   SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter();
   param2.ParameterName = "Stack";
   param2.Value = ex.StackTrace;

   cmd.Parameters.Add(param2);
```

etc.

To use [`AddWithValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx) you can do:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Login", user.Login);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Stack", ex.StackTrace);
```

Comment: Actually, that doesn't help because your reusing again the same parameter object. I believe that the second call to cmd.Parameters.Add will throw an exception because that parameter is already there. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @saamorim - off the top of my head I'm not 100% sure.  I have however adjusted my answer to include separate variables.

Comment: Doesn't work. Sql Exception about "Param is already know the cmd". I need to declare a new Sqlparameter object for each parameters.

Comment: @Portekoi - I've shown you how to do that.  You just need to make `param3` etc

Answer (score 1):

The way you are going about it, only the last parameter is getting added. There are several ways of adding parameters to the command object and the one below is among the easiest:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["intranetv2"].ConnectionString))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into [MyBase].[Dbo].[LogErrors] (Username, StackTrace, ShortDescription, DetailDescription, ErrorType) VALUES (@Login, @Stack, @Message, @Txt, @Source)", conn);

    conn.Open();

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Login", user.Login);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Stack", ex.StackTrace);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Message", ex.Message);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Txt", Txt);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Source", ex.Source);

    return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only added the last parameter to the parameter list.

Better would be this:

```
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@Login";
param.Value = user.Login;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

param = new SqlParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@Stack";
param.Value = ex.StackTrace;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

param = new SqlParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@Message";
param.Value = ex.Message;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

param = new SqlParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@Txt";
param.Value = Txt;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

param = new SqlParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@Source";
param.Value = ex.Source;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

conn.Open();
return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are reusing the **same** parameter instance for all parameters. That is plain wrong.

An easier way is to use the [`addWithValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) method instead:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Login", user.Login);
```

Note that the `@` is part of the name, so use it here too.

Answer (score 0):

There is a small mistake. Here is rectified code

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new  SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["intranetv2"].ConnectionString))
{

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into [MyBase].[Dbo].[LogErrors] (Username, StackTrace, ShortDescription, DetailDescription, ErrorType) VALUES (@Login, @Stack, @Message, @Txt, @Source)", conn);

            SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
            param.ParameterName = "@Login";
            param.Value = user.Login;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

            SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter();
            param2 .ParameterName = "@Stack";
            param2 .Value = ex.StackTrace;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param2);

            SqlParameter param3 = new SqlParameter();
            param3.ParameterName = "@Message";
            param3.Value = ex.Message;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param3);

            SqlParameter param4 = new SqlParameter();
            param4.ParameterName = "@Txt";
            param4.Value = Txt;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param4);

            SqlParameter param5 = new SqlParameter();
            param5.ParameterName = "@Source";
            param5.Value = ex.Source;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param5);

            conn.Open();
            return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

}

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're constantly changing the value of 'param', then only adding the very last version.

Try the following instead:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["intranetv2"].ConnectionString))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into [MyBase].[Dbo].[LogErrors] (Username, StackTrace, ShortDescription, DetailDescription, ErrorType) VALUES (@Login, @Stack, @Message, @Txt, @Source)", conn);

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@Login", Value = user.Login });
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@Stack", Value = ex.StackTrace });
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@Message", Value = ex.Message});
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@Txt", Value = Txt });
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@Source", Value = ex.Source});

    conn.Open();
    return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```