# Error: An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occured in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm new to ASP.NET and building a little dynamic website for a salesdepartment to registere their sales for salescompetions.

I have a page, after one is logged in, that consists of a couple of comboboxes/dropdowns and at the buttom a 'SUBMIT' button which I want to trigger a new record in the database with all the selected data. everything seems to go fine for a second but eventually the following error message appears:

**An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Invalid column name 'KunderID'.
Invalid column name 'KundeTypeID'.
Invalid column name 'MachineModellID'.
Invalid column name 'AntallID'.
Invalid column name 'BrukerID'.**

It points to the following part (The line starting with MBExec =) in the DBConnection.vb file:

```
Public Shared Function MBExec(ByVal SQL As String) As String
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(SQL, MBConn)
    MBExec = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
    cmd.Connection.Close()
End Function
```

On the sourcecode og the relevant page the relevant part of it is the following (bottom line starting with MBExec) whereby I cannot see that the columnsnames are wrong:

```
 Protected Sub RegisterSale(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim KundeNavn As DropDownList = DropDownListKundeNavn
    Dim TypeKunde As DropDownList = DropDownListTypeKunde
    Dim MachineModell As DropDownList = DropDownListMachineModell
    Dim Antall As DropDownList = DropDownListAntall
    Dim Bruker As DropDownList = DropDownListBruker


    If KundeNavn.SelectedItem.Text = "Velg" Then
        Dim msg = "Select or add a new customer"
        Dim msgTittle = "Missing Customer Name"
        MsgBox(msg, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, msgTittle)
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Dim msg1 = "Are you sure to continue?"
        Dim title = "Confirm Sale Registration"
        Dim style = MsgBoxStyle.YesNo
        Dim responce = MsgBox(msg1, style, title)
        If responce = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            Dim msg = "Thank you for your efforts, you are closer to becoming a sales champion!"
            Dim msgTittle = "Your Sale has been recorded"
            MsgBox(msg, MsgBoxStyle.Information, msgTittle)

            'Varibles to hold the DataValueField from the dropboxes
            Dim KundeID As Integer
            Dim TypeKundeID As Integer
            Dim MachineModellID As Integer
            Dim AntallID As Integer
            Dim BrukerID As Integer

            'Converts the DataValueField to an Integer 

            KundeID = Convert.ToInt32(KundeNavn.SelectedValue.ToString())
            TypeKundeID = Convert.ToInt32(TypeKunde.SelectedValue.ToString())
            MachineModellID = Convert.ToInt32(MachineModell.SelectedValue.ToString())
            AntallID = Convert.ToInt32(Antall.SelectedValue.ToString())
            BrukerID = Convert.ToInt32(Bruker.SelectedValue.ToString())

            MBExec("INSERT INTO KyoceraSalgReg(KunderID, KundeTypeID, MachineModellID, AntallID, BrukerID) Values (KunderID, KundeTypeID, MachineModellID, AntallID, BrukerID)")

            Exit Sub
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

I would very much appreciate if anybody could help me in the right direction here. If I understand it correctly, somehow the column names are not recognized and I just don't see why.

Cheers:)

Update 1:

MBExec looks like this:

```
    Public Shared Function MBExec(ByVal SQL As String) As String
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(SQL, MBConn)
    MBExec = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
    cmd.Connection.Close()
End Function
```

And KunderID datatype is string, selection made from a DropDownList

Comment: You are using the same variables that your trying to insert with to tell sql which columns to insert into and that is not the same as the column names are.

Comment: Hi thanks. I got rid of the Invalid Columns names errors but still one thing thats missing. Guessing it has to do with the second part of your answer about AddWithValue. I read the link and tried different things here but nothing seems to work. I really didnt understand that part:(

Comment: 'An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Must declare the scalar variable "@KunderID".'

Comment: What is the `KunderID` datatype? What does `MBExec` method look like? Edit your question with that info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Protected Sub RegisterSale(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim KundeNavn As DropDownList = DropDownListKundeNavn
    Dim TypeKunde As DropDownList = DropDownListTypeKunde
    Dim MachineModell As DropDownList = DropDownListMachineModell
    Dim Antall As DropDownList = DropDownListAntall
    Dim Bruker As DropDownList = DropDownListBruker

    'Varibles to hold the DataValueField from the dropboxes
    Dim KunderID As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(KundeNavn.SelectedValue.ToString())
    Dim TypeKundeID As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(TypeKunde.SelectedValue.ToString())
    Dim MachineModellID As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(MachineModell.SelectedValue.ToString())
    Dim AntallID As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(Antall.SelectedValue.ToString())
    Dim BrukerID As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(Bruker.SelectedValue.ToString())


    'Sets the Selected values from dropdownlist
    Dim ParamKunderID = New SqlParameter()
    ParamKunderID.ParameterName = "@KunderID"
    ParamKunderID.Value = KunderID

    Dim ParamTypeID = New SqlParameter
    ParamTypeID.ParameterName = "@KundeTypeID"
    ParamTypeID.Value = TypeKundeID

    Dim ParamMachineModellID = New SqlParameter()
    ParamMachineModellID.ParameterName = "@MachineModellID"
    ParamMachineModellID.Value = MachineModellID

    Dim ParamAntallID = New SqlParameter
    ParamAntallID.ParameterName = "@AntallID"
    ParamAntallID.Value = AntallID

    Dim ParamBrukerID = New SqlParameter
    ParamBrukerID.ParameterName = "@BrukerID"
    ParamBrukerID.Value = BrukerID

    If KundeNavn.SelectedItem.Text = "Velg" Then
        Dim msg = "Velg eller legge til en ny kunde"
        Dim msgTittle = "Mangler Kundenavn"
        MsgBox(msg, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, msgTittle)
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Dim msg1 = "Er du sikker på at du vil fortsette?"
        Dim title = "Bekrefte salg registrering"
        Dim style = MsgBoxStyle.YesNo
        Dim responce = MsgBox(msg1, style, title)

        If responce = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            MBExec("INSERT INTO KyoceraSalgReg(KunderID, KundeTypeID, MachineModellID, AntallID, BrukerID)" & " Values " & "(" & KunderID & "," & TypeKundeID & "," & MachineModellID & "," & AntallID & "," & BrukerID & ")")
            Dim msg = "Takk for din innsats, du er nærmere å bli et Salg Mester!"
            Dim msgtittle = "Din salget er registrert"
            MsgBox(msg, MsgBoxStyle.Information, msgtittle)

        End If


    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi DonA and Austine, Thank you so much. Austines answer was right on the Money and did the trick:)

Answer (score 2):

Try this approach:

```
MBExec("INSERT INTO KyoceraSalgReg(KunderID, KundeTypeID, MachineModellID, AntallID, BrukerID) Values (@KunderID, @KundeTypeID, @MachineModellID, @AntallID, @BrukerID)")
```

Use parameterized query to add the values:

```
cmd.Parameter.AddWithValue("@KunderID", KunderID)
```

[AddWithValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.110).aspx)

You may need to make separate instances of the SqlParameter - [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17366045/must-declare-the-scalar-variable-login-error-when-trying-to-add-parameter-to)